# Cannot tree-shake createRoot from react-dom-client (takes a large size as 900kb)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, vite, react-dom

I am building a ReactJS frontend with Vite.
I have been consistently getting this result in DevConsole on Chrome under Networks:

[image: My result from devconsole]
Do note that this is a dev server, not a build, but still **react-dom_client.js shows up as 900kb+** which is much more than I expected. The only thing I use from react-dom is this:

```
import {StrictMode} from 'react'
import {createRoot} from 'react-dom/client'
import App from './App.jsx'
import './App.css'

createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <StrictMode>
    <App />
  </StrictMode>,
)
```

Any issues in tree-shaking above? I believed that by pinpointing the import I would have reduced what gets loaded (and bundled up thereafter if we build too.)

While searching for this issues, I also stumbled upon this git issue too: https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/10354 which might be unrelated, but it states a more practical size that we should get with and without building, let alone compression.

Answer (score 0):

This should be completely normal size. I've had about the same size for a starter too, earliest check was about half a year ago and I checked it twice after that. I also asked my collague and he made a new vite react project quick and the size was about the same.

Comment: I would rather not allow that size take up 90% of my bundle size, there must be a tree shaking issue here